# NSData / NSString Persisting Sessions and HTTP Auth vs Name/Value Pair

Tags: php, ios, session, rest

**Q1:** If I fill the contents of an `NSData` or `NSString` object using `dataWithContentsOfURL` or `stringWithContentsOfURL` respectively from within my app, will subsequent requests register on the web server within the same session (PHP in my case)? Or will they all arrive creating new sessions?

**Q2:** What is are the advantages, if any, of using HTTP based Authentication (like in RESTful services) vs submitting the u/p pair via https?

Comment: Please ask Q2 as a separate question. Q1 and Q2 are not related and the title does not imply anything about Q2.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1: No, they don't keep session, you need to use at least `NSURLConnection`
For Q2: The difference is that the HTTPS connection is encrypted and it would be difficult to be sniffed or hijacked and in the HTTP based authentication the credentials are actually send in plain text, so if someone is sniffing the network could easily find them...

Comment: What if I used HTTP style authentication in a https context? By http style authentication, I mean issuing an authentication header with base64 encoded credentials. At that point, are they virtually the same?

Comment: No the rest of the requests and responses, together with the session cookie will be in plain text.